# Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin-android']

Tags: android, kotlin

this issue due to mismatched `kotlin-gradle-plugin` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle`, in my case i was use

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4` and bump up version to `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31` to address the issue just use matched version of AGP and KGP

Comment: I had this problem, and found that deleting the build folder and then rerunning the build fixed it.

Comment: no, it didn't work out in my case. i was bumped up the gradle plugin and suddenly got this issue so i had to bump up agp and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To address the use matched versions like so.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
```

but if you using AGP 7.0.3, make sure you have these version for KGP and Hilt Gradle Plugin like so.

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31'
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.39.1'
```